# MS Word 2016: Mailmerge field currency formatting issue

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge, currency-formatting, regional-settings

I am working on a Word document (Word 2016), which contains several mailmerge fields. One of those fields is a currency field. My data source is an Excel spreadsheet.

In the Excel spreadsheet, the field is in currency format. I am using a Greek localized currency format, which has **"." for thousands separator** and **"," for the decimal separator**. My Windows 10 regional settings are also configured this way. I want that format to appear in the Word mailmerge field. But, alas, it does not.

I have tried various formats, some of which are the following:

- \# #.#,0
- \# #.#,00
- \# ,#.0
- \# "#,#.0"

For example, when I use the first format, I get the following result:
**€62,202,660,000,000,000. 0**.
This is not just the wrong format. The number is actually 62202 but Word gets completely confused. The other formats I use produce similarly invalid results.

It seems that Word completely ignores my Windows system settings (which specify "," for decimal and "." for thousands) and always uses the defaults, meaning "." for decimal and "," for thousands.

How can I achieve my desired format? Why does not Word use the system settings or at least the formatting of the Excel column I use?